# Extended class of TcpClient doesn't accept with EndAcceptTcpClient(ar) function

Tags: vb.net, networking, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I've created a new class which inherits the `TcpClient` class :

```
Public Class MyTcpClient
    Inherits Net.Sockets.TcpClient

    Private _ClintName As String

    Sub New(ByVal host As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal ClientName As String)
        MyBase.New(host,port)
        _ClintName = ClientName
    End Sub

    Public Property ClientName()
        Get
            Return _ClintName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            _ClintName = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I tried to connect to an instance of `TcpListener`:

```
Try
    client = New MyTcpClient(ip, port , "ClientName")
Catch ex As Exception
    xUpdate("Can't connect to the server!")
End Try
```

However on the server side, there is a problem with the `EndAcceptTcpClient` function. The server side code is something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim NewClient As MyTcpClient
    Listning = New TcpListener(GetMyIP, 3818)
    Listning.Start()
    UpdateList("Server Starting", False)
    Listning.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listning)
End Sub

Sub AcceptClient(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    NewClient = Listning.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)
    UpdateList("New Client Joined!", True)
    Listning.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), Listning)
End Sub
```

The error is occuring on the first line of the `AcceptClient` sub :

```
NewClient = Listning.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)
```

The error message is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient' to type 'ServerChat.MyTcpClient'.

If I change `MyTcpClient` to `TcpClient` everything will be ok.

Should I do any changes on the `TcpListener` object or is my attempt wrong?